# Is Bundle ID Suffix the same as the bundle identifier in info.plist?

Tags: iphone, submission

What is Bundle ID Suffix? Tutorials said to use Bundle ID from `info.plist`; I can notice Bundle identifier in `info.plist`, its value is `com.yourcompany.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`

Should I type `(com.yourcompany.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` as Bundle ID Suffix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bundle ID is in the format `com.yourcompany.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`

The Xcode project takes the default value for the Bundle ID as above. In that, the `$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` gives the product name.

Here, `(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` is the Bundle ID Suffix.

Let us consider you have created a project named "HelloWorld". For this project, the `$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` returns the "HelloWorld" as the productName. This will be the Bundle ID Suffix.

Comment: hmm, are you sure? I had to sumbit: com.companynameblabl.appname as "suffix"

Comment: One thing you have to understand. While executing the code in to the device, you need to set the provisioning profiles, for that you need to set the bundle identifier in the info.plist. So while submitting the app to appstore, select the bundle name as you specified for the profile.

For Ex: If the profile has bundle identifier as com.companynameblabl.appname, then you can give that "appname"  as suffix.

Comment: what's wrong if i use appnameXXX as my suffix?? will apple approve my app??

Comment: @Risma: Hi, You can give any suffix. Default is AppName. But the you should remember one thing, that suffix should match with the Bundle suffix in the App Details(That mean while uploading the App to the store, you will give some details about the App. There you will give bundleIdentifier. There it should match). And also that identifier should match with the provisioning profile. If every thing matches, then apple will approve your App. Finally, be sure that, your full bundle identifier, shouldn't match with any other Apps identifier.

Comment: So if my companies domain name extension is .gov would my bundle id be gov.mycompanyname.myappname?

Comment: @VanceSmith:  As per the apple developer account, we can create our bundle id as com.domainname.appname or com.domainname.* and also you can give "*" while creating app Id, so you can give any thing for the bundle id.